# Как изменить тело метода в рантайме при помощи reflection?

Tags: java

Необходимо изменять тело метода в рантайме, всегда по разному, очень много вариаций.
Если подробнее, то в зависимости от полей класса, необходимо изменить 2 метода.
Можно ли это реализовать с помощью reflections?

Есть проект на Swing, почти все экраны в нем построены по модели MVC. Нужно достать из вьюшки некие визуальные элементы (текст филды, кнопки, checkbox и т.д.), потом засеттить имя и добавить к каждому элементу дополнительны наблюдатель, потом удалить наблюдатель при закрытии вьюшки. И всё это нужно делать в рантайме.

имя имеет вид "elementTipe" + "elementName"
пример buttonAdd

Comment: @MaxBel, reflection - это самое последнее, к чему стоит прибегать. Наверняка есть решения получше. Опишите задачу подробнее, и мы попробуем вам помочь.

Comment: Может, вам будет достаточно наследования и перекрытия виртуальных методов?

Comment: А в чём проблема в новой постановке задачи? Что мешает в рантайме оббежать вьюшку, приклеить по наблюдателю, подписаться на закрытие вьюшки и когда это закрытие произойдёт, отписаться?

Comment: Проект огромный, и трудный, кажется что наследованием тут будет не управиться.

Comment: VladD так и делается сейчас, но там ещё нужно сеттить имена, и сейчас они все засеччены ручками, вот хочется добиться автоматизации добавления имен и добавления/удаления обзерверов.

Хочется решить эту задачу более динамично, если я правильно понимаю динамическое программирование.

Comment: @MaxBel: Окей, то есть вы хотите зарефакторить методы ручной установки всяких штук на что-то более продвинутое. Хорошая идея. Может, приведите какой-нибудь кусок кода, подумаем, как его обобщить.

Comment: @MaxBel, какие имена вы хотите засеттить? У вас что, доступ к полям идёт через динамически присваиваемые имена?

Comment: VladD вот тут проблема, я не могу постить код нигде(,такие заказчики. 

Сам по себе код ничего особенного из себя не представляет. Это свинговое приложение, причем уже очень давно написанное (по ITшным меркам). Оптимизируем новую фичу.

Достать поля класса можно при помощи reflections (судя по коментам это не луший способ, хотя пока не понятно почему - я нуб мне ещё много предстоит узнать)

Сгенерить имена - это просто.

есть метод в котором добавляет обзерверы

private void processView{
someButton1.addActionLisoner(someObject)
}
Непонятно как изменить содержимое этого метода в рантайме?

Comment: @MaxBel: код свинговой части не нужен. Нужен код, который получает по контролу определяет его тип и выполняет действия. (Собственно, ваш код.) Вы можете по вьюшке [получить все контролы в ней](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/GettingtheChildComponentsofaContainer.htm), вы ведь этим пользуетесь, да?

Comment: Вот мой код пока ещё не написан, вопрос задан как бы заранее, чтобы не писать говнкод и сначала побольше подумать, и поговорить с умными людьми.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Касательно изменения тела метода в рантайм, то общая схема решения задачи примерно такая:

1. Допустим есть несколько вариантов метода в виде компилированных образов, как вариант можно создавать исходники "на лету" и компилировать их тоже "на лету" через [Java Compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)
2. Применяем [JavaAssist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javassist) добавляя все имеющиеся варианты объектников в пул `JavaAssist.ClassPool`
3. Далее уже средствами JavaAssist можно спокойно запускать/использовать нужную копию объектника загруженного в пул - пример [здесь](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0916/index.html#h1)

Кроме JavaAssist сходные задачи решают и другие либы приведенные в других ответах. Все эти либы используют 3 API Java:

1. Java reflection
2. [Java ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)
3. [Java Attach API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/attach/) - API для присоединения объектников к JVM "на лету"

Только сочетание этих 3-х API позволяет достичь задачи манипуляции объектными кодами в рантайме, поодиночке, просто рефлексией или кастомным загрузчиком классов это не решается.

**Update**

Описанная вами задача достаточно проста и не требует привлечения фигур высшего пилотажа, так что берите лучше наследование и спокойно сделайте как положено.

Comment: @Barmaley: на самом деле, ТС'у не нужна такая мощь. Ему нужно всего лишь обойти контролы в дереве визуальных элементов и понавешивать обсерверов.

Comment: Да, конечно, я согласен - см. апдейт

Comment: Извеняюсь, некорректно сформулировал вопрос

Answer (score 0):

- [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/)
- [Javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/)

Comment: спасибо! Скоро посмотрю.